Trying to find the title of a Mystery Science Theater episode with the riff "not just any arrow, a good arrow"
I saw this episode when it aired on the Scifi channel with my mom, probably around 15 years ago. I was very young at the time so I can't remember what the movie was, only that there was a scene where the main character shot the monster with a (flaming?) arrow, and one of the bots made a joke along the lines of "not just any arrow, a really good arrow" 
I realize that this is not much to go by, but it's been driving me crazy!

Do you remember anything else about it? Was the movie in color or black and white? Was the main character a man or a woman? What was the genre of the movie (fantasy, western, modern, etc)? Do you recall whether Joel or Mike was the host? If you could edit the question to include any additional information, it would be a great help.

Track of the Moon Beast
It was an episode from the 10th season, using footage from the awful film of the same name.
The scene you're describing occurs just after 1 hour, 23 mins and 20 seconds in (video below links to it):



And thanks for posting this question - I'd never heard of Mystery Science Theater before, and I found the footage I watched to find the exact timestamp absolutely hilarious.
